set difference of a column in spark dataframe
I have a dataframe like this :



col A
col B
col C




A
C
[A,C]


B
D
[A,D]



and I have a set declared
set A = [A, B, C, D]
I want a set difference between set A and col C like below



col A
col B
col C




A
C
[B,D]


B
D
[B,C]



How do I do that ?

What did you try so far? What's blocking you?
